# java coding to get multiple comment in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I am getting only one comment and it is getting updated when a new comment is posted but i want to see all comments posted, where i am wrong?

Comment servlet

```
  String comment=request.getParameter("myTextarea");  //i stored myTextarea in string  comment            
   ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList emp_list =new ArrayList();                                     
     al1.add(comment);                     
      emp_list.add(al1);                                         
      request.setAttribute("empList",emp_list);        
      String nextJSP = "/result.jsp";//goes to result.jsp
     RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

result.jsp

```
    <%
     try{
      int i=0;
      if(request.getAttribute("empList")!=null)
       {
       ArrayList al3 = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("empList");
        Iterator itr = al3.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
        ArrayList empList = (ArrayList)itr.next();
         String newcomment="";
          try{
          newcomment=(String)empList.get(i++);
          }
         catch(Exception e){
          }   
        try{
      out.println(newcomment);// i am getting only one comment here
         }
     catch(Exception e){
     }   
     }
    }
  }//end of try block
    catch(Exception e){
   out.println(e); 
   }
   %>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in your java it looks like you are putting only one comment in your `empList`, that is why you only see one comment.

assuming the url looks like `www.some.url/resource?myTextarea=somestring` ...

```
String comment=request.getParameter("myTextarea"); 
//so now comment equals to "somestring"

ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList emp_list =new ArrayList();                                     
al1.add(comment);
//now al1 equals ["somestring"]                     

emp_list.add(al1);
//now emp_list equals [["somestring"]]
```

see, you only have one comment in the emp_list, so you will get one comment in your jsp.

Further more, the code you have written in jsp is weird, why do you have 
`newcomment=(String)empList.get(i++);`? I am pretty sure you will get an OutOfIndexException soon with this code, unless you have some special data structure storing the comments in mind. Right now it looks like your data structure have a list of list where each list within the list contains one comment like this?
`[["comment1"], ["comment2"], ["comment3"], ...]`

Comment: ok but what may be the solution? how will i get multiple comments?

Comment: How will you get multiple comments depends on the whole design of your website. You gotta give us more detail about your website so we can help you. It looks like you are trying to grab comments from the a html page? If so, what's the HTML code of that page?

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong in not using jstl :)

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:forEach items = "${empList}" var = "comment">
  <c:out value = "${comment}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Allthough I can see that my code will not work in your example, my question is, why do you have a list in a list just to list the comments?

Comment: ya i will use jstl but i am trying with scriplets tag first